# Java EE Make a timer with millisecond interval to send packets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, websocket, glassfish

Java EE is a behemoth to me, and I've already asked a very similar question just a day ago, but didn't get any adequate responses.

Simply put, I want to make a timer loop for my GlassFish server that is going to continuously send packets of information to ANY client connected via a websocket.

I want this to send packets A LOT (every few milliseconds), as this is for an implementation of a game.

I've looked at one suggestion that uses the `@Schedule` annotation, but that only times at most once per second, which is very NOT adequate for what I'm doing.

I've looked on the web, but I don't even know what keywords to use to find what I'm looking for in Java. Any tips?

Comment: Do you send a snapshots of the game state to all players every x milliseconds, or do you send a message immediately when a player performs an action. If you send snapshots, you need a timer, if you push messages you don't need a timer (but you may need additional threads for sending messages). In order to answer how you implement the timer we need to know if the game is distribute over multiple servers, or if you can just use the Timer class from Java to trigger every push.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) in conjunction with the [@Timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Timeout.html) annotation to work with millisecond intervals.

```
package my.example;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class IntervalTest {
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // Start after 1 seconds, subsequently every 50 milliseconds
        timerService.createTimer(1000, 50, "IntervalTest");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) {
        // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I've run into a different issue. I can't use @Startup on this Bean I'm instantiating that will send packets. It keeps telling me I cannot instantiate a Singleton that can run into Exceptions, but I need to throw Exceptions in order to send JsonObjects to my websocket. Any tips?